# Added text in EditText hosted by ListView row is removed upon keyboard closing

Tags: android

I use following GUI setup:

- ListView activity
- CursorAdapter that feeds this list
- Layout for activity
- Layout for rows in ListView :

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:gravity = "right" >
      <TextView android:id="@+id/text_9_description_top"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
      </TextView>
      <CheckBox android:id="@+id/chkApprovedTabChapter9"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_9_description_top"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="right" >
      </CheckBox>
      <Button android:id="@+id/tabchaprter9_row_button_delete"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="leftBtn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkApprovedTabChapter9" >
      </Button>
      <Button android:id="@+id/tabchaprter9_row_button_edit"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tabchaprter9_row_button_delete"
          android:text="rightBtn" android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit">
      </Button>
      <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/text_9_description_bottom"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tabchaprter9_row_button_edit"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="right"
          android:layout_alignParentRight ="true"
          android:inputType="text" 
          android:imeOptions="normal">
      </EditText>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Row Layout contains EditText, checkbox and couple of buttons. ListView is filled with setAdapter ().  Apparently ListView is created correctly, I see all rows with data.

First problem : I would like to initially show EditText as disabled so user cant edit text immediately. Only after clicking on "edit" button in the row EditText  must became available for typing. Setting enable "false" has no effect on EditText (tried bot in code and in XML attribs) EditText is always editable.

Second issue: Typing in EditText using softkeyboard looks fine - I see all changes, however when I close softkeyboard (either pressing Android back button or "hide" button on keyboard) all added text is removed and EditText is reverted to its initial stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than enabling and disabling it try with `focussable= "false"` this will have desirable effect.

Answer (score 0):

For first issue: add this attribute in XML file `android:visibility="invisible"`
And in the edit button onClickListener make the visibility as  edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE).

make it clear for 2nd issue

Comment: 2nd case : Im typing into one of EditText widgets using software keyboard (Im on Samsung Galaxy tab). I see new text adding to the EdtiText while Im typing. When I finish typing and dismissing the keyboard (press "Back" button on tablet or "hide" button on softkeyboard a newly added text disappears and EditText returns to the original stage. Hope this is clear.   I suspect its somehow related ot the ListView conatiner as I don't have this problem on other activities where EditText are not hosted in ListView row.

Answer (score 0):

first problem : you cannot disable EditText, write code to show TextView and hide EditText for disable EditText mode and vice versa for enable mode.

Second Problem: go to setting -> language and keyboard under text setting disable other languages and keep Android Keyborad on.

Comment: Thanks for , regarding second problem I tried this and it does not help (perhaps Im doing something wrong), more over I need input in 2 different languages ...